I can't change layout using super +space
After the latest update of the Ubuntu 24.04, i cannot change keyboard layout using super+space.
Keyboard-checking sites detect super as a "left click ". How can i fix this bug?

possibly related bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1956916
